# app has already been declared within try/catch

Tags: javascript, electron, eslint

I have the following `try/catch`:

```
try {
    var { app } = require('electron').remote;
} catch (e) {
    var { app } = require('electron');
}
```

Even though it is valid, ESLint is having an issue that says `app` has already been declared.

So, I try and move the var above the `try/catch` and there is an error with the `=` saying that it is an `Unexpected token` like so:

```
var app;
try {
    { app } = require('electron').remote;
} catch (e) {
    { app } = require('electron');
}
```

What is the proper way to do this so ESLint doesn't complain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, since you're clearly using ES2015+ (aka "ES6+"), look at using `let` or `const` rather than `var`. There's basically no use for `var` in an ES2015+ world. (But both of the below will work with `var` as well.)

The parsing problem is because `{` looks like the beginning of a block. You can wrap the entire assignment in `()` to get around that:

```
let app;
try {
    ({ app } = require('electron').remote);
} catch (e) {
    ({ app } = require('electron'));
}
```

Example (faking `require`):

```js
// fake require
function require(name) {
  return {app: {name: "I'm the app"}};
}

let app;
try {
  ({ app } = require('electon').remote);
} catch (e) {
  ({ app } = require('electron'));
}
console.log(app);
```

Or just don't use destructuring at all:

```
let app;
try {
    app = require('electron').remote.app;
} catch (e) {
    app = require('electron').app;
}
```

```js
// fake require
function require(name) {
  return {app: {name: "I'm the app"}};
}

let app;
try {
  app = require('electron').remote.app;
} catch (e) {
  app = require('electron').app;
}
console.log(app);
```

Comment: I usually use `let`, but I couldn't really get that working either. Is `var` basically deprecated?

Comment: :-) I added live examples.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: *"Is `var` basically deprecated?"* In my view, it's a matter of style. But for my own work, yes, I only use `const` and `let`. (Mostly `const` -- turns out, if you keep functions short and you're dealing with objects a lot, it's frequently the case you don't have to change the value of a variable once you've assigned it.) I've seen several writers in the JavaScript space recommend never using `var` as well.

Comment: Okay that is kind of what I was thinking. I was using var here because of the different scopes. This way looks more of my style!

Answer (score -1):

`var` declares a value in the scope of the current function. A `try` statement does not create that kind of scope, so you're re-declaring `app` in your initial code. That's why it doesn't pass linting.

You can use `let` instead of `var`, if `app` is only needed within `try` or `catch` blocks.

Comment: Whereupon the code trying to use `app` after the `try`/`catch` would fail.

Comment: Like I said - "if app is only needed within try or catch blocks"

Comment: Well, it clearly *isn't* needed only in the blocks. It's quite obvious what the code is trying to do.